# How to create a new VPC Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am doing a AWS course and following steps how to create a MySql database. When I started creating the database, At Additional Connectivity Configuration -> VPC Security Group, I am not able to find Choose Existing and Create New options. How I can create a new VPC?

This pic from the course so you can see both options Choose Existing and Create New

[image]

This pic is where I am trying to create a new VPC but I dont have the option:
[image]

Here is pic from course:
[image]

Created a new VCP but I just can choose default not the one I created:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: RDS Database Connectivity Section]

There have been UI changes to the AWS console so that's the reason for the differences in your video course and current AWS console.

Just click on the choicefield and you'll be able to see the `Create new VPC` item.

--- UPDATE ---

That name shown in the video course is `Name` tag, You can't see it cause you haven't made any VPC with `Name` tag. You can't define VPC id, that is auto generated.
Solution 1:
Make a VPC with `Name` tag, and then you can see it.
Solution 2:
Create the VPC inside your RDS creation and edit VPC tags later in VPC settings and add `Name` tag.

Comment: If I select Create new VPC, but still I am unable to write my own name in VPC Security Group.  The New VPC Security Group Name is not displaying.

Comment: That name shown in the video course is `Name` tag, You can't see it cause you haven't made any VPC with `Name` tag. You can't define VPC id, that is auto generated.
Solution 1:
Make a VPC with `Name` tag, and then you can see it.
Solution 2:
Create the VPC inside your RDS creation and edit VPC tags later in VPC settings and add `Name` tag.

Comment: I added a new pic from course, once he choose Create new then he is able to Enter VPC security group name. But I am  unable to Enter VPC.

Comment: He is able to write name for it as he has done it before in his other VPCs.
Just create a new VPC from the VPC section and make a tag named `Name` and then you can see it in your RDS creation section.
Just follow the steps and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Created a new VCP but I just can choose default not the one I created

Comment: Are you sure that you've created the VPC in the same region as the RDS instance you are trying to create?

Comment: Yes, It is in the same region